# Order wp_query by calculated field

Tags: wp-query, posts-where

Hi I'm working on a store locator. 
I have a custom post "clinics" where I save clinic details (address,.., lat, lng). Each time I publish a new clinic I save post_id, lat and lng also in a custom table "lat_lng_post".

I'm able to search clinics within a specific distance using filter post_where in this way:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'location_posts_where' )


    function location_posts_where( $where )
        {
            // $lat  and $ lng are latitude and longitude of the searched point
            global $wpdb;    
            $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post 
                 WHERE
                 (6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                  * cos( radians( lat ) )
                  * cos( radians( lng )
                  - radians(" . $lng . ") )
                  + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                  * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= 150 
                    ORDER BY 
                        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                  * cos( radians( lat ) )
                  * cos( radians( lng )
                  - radians(" . $lng . ") )
                  + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                  * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) ASC)";
                        return $where;
                    }
```

I get the clinics within the fixed distance (150km) but not ordered according to the distance. They are shown according to the post date. 
I tried to set orderby to none:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'clinica',
    'orderby'                => 'none'

);
```

But It didn't work. How can I force to order by that ORDER BY rule I set in the query?

Comment: try putting the order by into the filter `posts_orderby`. [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)

Comment: It means that I have to use LEFT JOIN?
I'll try.

Comment: no it doesn't. there is a filter for WHERE clause and also for ORDER BY. You just have to separate your code.

Comment: and ignore the $args orderby... you filter `posts_order_by` for your CPT and this should overwrite any other orderby given by $args. **edit** where did you get your `$lat` resp. `$lng` in the code. if they aren't defined, they will return 0;

Answer (score 0):

Using `WP_Query`, you can order the results by `meta_value_num`:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'clinica',
    'meta_key'  => 'distance_field_name',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: I don't have that field. The distance is calculated using the havering formula inside the post_where and lat and lng are stored in a custom table.